# How to run php extencioned files in CMD (DOS)?

Tags: php, cmd

Is there a possibility to run a php file by using the cmd? So it will become much easier to see things without using any html codes in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show Desktop.

Right Click My Computer shortcut in the desktop.

Click Properties.

You should see a section of control Panel - Control Panel\System and Security\System.

Click Advanced System Settings on the Left menu.

Click Enviornment Variables towards the bottom of the window.

Select PATH in the user variables list.

Append your PHP Path (C:\myfolder\php) to your PATH variable, separated from the already existing string by a semi colon.

Click OK

Open your "cmd"

Type PATH, press enter

Make sure that you see your PHP folder among the list.

That should work.

Note: Make sure that your PHP folder has the php.exe. It should have the file type CLI. If you do not have the php.exe, go ahead and check the installation guidelines at - http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php - and download the installation file from there.